# What are the full form of SAPI, PAPI and EAPI? What are the difference and when to use what?

Tags: api, sapi

I am front end developer and recently hearing these new terms (new to me). I searched Google for explanation but got more confused with multiple full forms.

- SAPI: System API/ Server API
- PAPI: Process API/ Performance API
- EAPI: Enterprise API/ Experience API

Until now, I was creating REST API end points with Node JS and Express/ Mongoose, but never felt the need to divide my API in above categories. Please guide me on when to use what and how to implement the same. TIA.

Comment: The [tag:papi] tag is about the Linux Performance API which includes system-calls like `perf_event_open` that Linux `perf` uses to access performance counters like `branch-misses` and `cpu_clk_unhalted.thread`  It's completely unrelated to APIs used over HTTPS.

Answer (score 1):

System APIs (SAPI) are APIs such as rest services or microservices that are responsible for connecting to the system (Back through Rest services or a Queue, SaaS, Cloud, Web Services Database, etc.) they do not have processes, their function is to bring and bring resources (these are somewhat more recent terms introduced by MuleSoft.

The Process API (PAPI), are APIs in charge of processing all the business logic and can be PAPI of microservices.

The Experience APIs are apis used in UI/UX, in the front, and usually, they no longer use all the information that the PAPI uses, so each one is responsible for receiving and mapping to be able to use the data or rename it to be able to display or use it as desired

Client <-> PAPI< -> SAPI<-> (Back or other source or resource of information)

Answer (score 0):

This is related to API-led Connectivity paradigm.
Find more details here: [API-led Connectivity](https://blogs.mulesoft.com/learn-apis/api-led-connectivity/what-is-api-led-connectivity/)

Also I've seen this paradigm implemented at mainframe approaches. I'd like to know if someone else know its implementation with microservices architecture.